# UITableView not showing UITableViewCell text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` created in a `xib`.

1. The delegate and datasource outlets are set
2. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is there
3. `numberOfRowsInSection` is there
4. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called

I can set the background color of the cell and it works fine. However, setting the `textLabel` of the `UITableViewCell` does not work.

Here is my code:

```
...
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UITableView datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[[PropertyManager sharedManager] fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Property *property = [[[PropertyManager sharedManager] fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //This DOES prints to the console properly
    NSLog(@"%@", property.descriptionShort);

    [cell.textLabel setText:property.descriptionShort];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - 
- (void)filterToUsersLocation {}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*
     I tried with a custom UITableViewCell that didn't work either
    [self.table registerClass:[PropertyCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [self.table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PropertyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     */
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.table reloadData];
}
...
```

The only thing that is different in my setup is that the UIViewController that contains this UITableView is being added as a childViewController to a parent UIViewController. Which lead me to believe that this was the problem at first, but since setting the background color of the cell works fine, I don't believe it to be some UIView covering it issue.

---

Here is some screens:

The base screen:
[image]

---

Screen when setting the background color to blue:
[image]

---

**EDIT**

I've added a few more log statements which is makes things even more confusing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Property *property = [[[PropertyManager sharedManager] fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //This DOES prints to the console properly
    NSLog(@"%@", property.descriptionShort);
    //Prints out __NSCFString properly
    NSLog(@"%@", [property.descriptionShort class]);

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [cell.textLabel setText:property.descriptionShort];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    //Prints out correctly
    NSLog(@"cellTextLabel = %@", cell.textLabel.text);

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Prints out correctly
    NSLog(@"cell textLabel = %@", cell.textLabel.text);
}
```

---

```
<UITableView: 0x151c8c00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1469e340>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1469d9c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x1469eab0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1469eba0>>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x1462b4e0; frame = (0 528; 320 44); text = '
      Grand 6 Bd Home on...'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1462b670>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x1462bba0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1462b3b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1462bd70>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1462bf20; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1462c5f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1462bf90>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1462c740; frame = (15 0; 290 43.5); text = '

    . . .
    . . .  
    . . .

   | <UIImageView: 0x1466dc10; frame = (0 564.5; 320 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1466dca0>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x1469e030; frame = (316.5 561; 3.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1466dcd0>>
```

Comment: Are you sure if your text is not blank or nil?

Comment: Yes, I log the text out to console in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and it logs out fine.

Comment: a) do `NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text)` before returning the cell b) do `[tableView recursiveDescription]`  or just `[cell recursiveDescription]` in the console to see if there's something wrong with the view layout. For (b), put a breakpoint in some event handler in your code that you can trigger, such as `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @TimothyMoose I've updated my question with new code, thanks for taking the time to look at this

Comment: Great. Now do `po [tableView recursiveDescription] in the console and check that the frames are were you expect. Also, check the font and color.

Comment: @TimothyMoose I've check all of those and it is all correct. I'm about to post the output of recursiveDescription, the only thing that stands out is the `UITableViewWrapperView`, other than that everything seems OK.

Comment: I'm stumped unless you can post a sample project.

Comment: @TimothyMoose *facepalm* I'm blaming it on a lack of sleep but I just noticed when logging out the text that there was a carriage return, ARRRGGGHHH!! So after reformatting the strings it showed up in the cells fine. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Hah. That is actually visible in the log statements you posted. I just thought it was the console wrapping the text to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if property.descriptionShort store NSString object and also check for compilation warnings.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [property.descriptionShort class]);
```

Comment: I've updated my question wish more code, but adding this it prints out __NSCFString correctly

Comment: There may be 1-2 rows which are going under navigation bar and hence you are not able to see the rows. How many objects (rows) you have in the array? Simplify these embedded calls and put them in local variables for clarification and easy debugging.

Comment: All of the blue rows should have text in them, so hiding under the navigation bar is not the issue.

Comment: Try setting some static text in the textLabel - like @"row" etc.

Comment: I can't believe this led me to the answer but logging out static text worked. So then I looked closer at my data and saw that there was a carriage return at the beginning of it so the text was being set, but it's format put it off screen. Thanks for your help!